# STM32F4 Adjust linker script to save memory for EEPROM emulation

Tags: stm32, flash

I need to reserve FLASH for my the virutal EEPROM emulation on an STM32F405VGT6:

https://www.mouser.ch/datasheet/2/389/stm32f405rg-956214.pdf

The pages I need are in Sector 2 and Sector 3 of the flash and so not at the end of the flash region. So i need something like this:

```
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
CCMRAM (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 32k
EMULATED_EEPROM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x8008000 LENGTH=2*16k
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8008000+2*16k, LENGTH = 1024k-(32k+2*16k)
}
```

But this ofc. does not work. How can I adjust the linker script to achieve this partition reservation of the flash memory?

[image: Flash]

Linker Script:

```
/*
*****************************************************************************
**

**  File        : stm32_flash.ld
**
**  Abstract    : Linker script for STM32F405VG Device with
**                1024KByte FLASH, 128KByte RAM
**
**                Set heap size, stack size and stack location according
**                to application requirements.
**
**                Set memory bank area and size if external memory is used.
**
**  Target      : STMicroelectronics STM32
**
**  Environment : Atollic TrueSTUDIO(R)
**
**  Distribution: The file is distributed as is, without any warranty
**                of any kind.
**
**  (c)Copyright Atollic AB.
**  You may use this file as-is or modify it according to the needs of your
**  project. This file may only be built (assembled or compiled and linked)
**  using the Atollic TrueSTUDIO(R) product. The use of this file together
**  with other tools than Atollic TrueSTUDIO(R) is not permitted.
**
*****************************************************************************
*/

/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20020000;    /* end of RAM */
/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x200;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
CCMRAM (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 1024K
}

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH

  _siccmram = LOADADDR(.ccmram);

  /* CCM-RAM section 
  * 
  * IMPORTANT NOTE! 
  * If initialized variables will be placed in this section,
  * the startup code needs to be modified to copy the init-values.  
  */
  .ccmram :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sccmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at ccmram start */
    *(.ccmram)
    *(.ccmram*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eccmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at ccmram end */
  } >CCMRAM AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough RAM left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >RAM



  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try (never tested myself)

```
MEMORY
{
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
CCMRAM (rw)      : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
FLASH_1 (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8000000, LENGTH = 32k
EMULATED_EEPROM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x8008000 LENGTH=2*16k
FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x8008000+2*16k, LENGTH = 1024k-(32k+2*16k)
}

  .text2 :  
  {  
    ...  
  } >> FLASH_1

  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH_1
```

but to place anything in the text2 section (some functions for example) you will have to declare them   with  `__attribute__ ((section ("text2")))`

Answer (score 6):

You were pretty close - just give them different names and make sure everything is in the right places.

The below should work (I have similar code working) but note that it will waste most of the first page having only the ISR vector there (which is under 1k). You may add an additional section there - but it will need specially marking stuff that goes in there in the code and IMO is not worth the effort for that measly 1.5% of total flash.

As a side note - such a setup tended to confuse my debugger (don't know if it was GDB itself or QtCreator giving GDB wrong data) so I ended up using a different linker script for debugging purposes.

```
MEMORY
{
    RAM (xrw)               : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
    CCMRAM (rw)             : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 64K
    FLASH_BOOT (rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,
                              LENGTH = 32k
    EMULATED_EEPROM (rwx)   : ORIGIN = ORIGIN(FLASH_BOOT) + LENGTH(FLASH_BOOT), 
                              LENGTH=2*16k
    FLASH (rx)              : ORIGIN = ORIGIN(EMULATED_EEPROM) + LENGTH(EMULATED_EEPROM),
                              LENGTH = 1024k - LENGTH(FLASH_BOOT) - LENGTH(EMULATED_EEPROM)
}

SECTIONS
{
    .isr_vector :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >FLASH_BOOT

    /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
    .text :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
        *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
        *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
        *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
        *(.eh_frame)

        KEEP (*(.init))
        KEEP (*(.fini))

        . = ALIGN(4);
        _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
    } >FLASH
}
```

Comment: Perfect, now it works great.

Comment: @HansPeterLoft if it works you might consider accepting the answer?

Comment: I have the same issue as OP and tried this solution - It compiles well and the debugger correctly starts in main, but once a function in a separate .cpp file is called, the mcu hardfaults. (0x605122c <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x605122c>) - Any ideas what I missed?

Comment: @antipattern the address in your error message doesn't look right - I haven't worked with STM32 for over two years, but that's lower than even the RAM. Are you trying to access a peripheral? Or maybe you have an uninitialized variable?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, it was caused by an ill-formed read to the flash memory that was performed in the constructor of some nested class member that got initialized in the scope of that function call. Stupid mistake on my side. Great answer though!